# How can I convert Shift_JIS character codes to unicode characters in python?

Tags: python, encoding, character, shift-jis

I have a list of Shift_JIS character codes (in integers) that I want to convert into unicode characters. I think I need a version of the `chr()/unichr()` function that works in other encodings. 
I've tried `decode()` in combination with `hex()`, but it only decodes the string itself, not the hexadecimal value.

Example input and output:

```
input = [91, 92, 48, 528]

output = ["[", "¥", "0", "０"]
```

Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this work: 
`shift_str = chr(shift_int // 256) + chr(shift_int % 256)` then 
`shift_uni = unicode(shift_str, 'shift-jis')`

Comment: Can you show samples of the input and output you'll need?

Comment: What do you mean by "in integers"? Do you have a list of `int` type values? Or a string that contains human-formatted, base 10 numbers (i.e. only the symbols `0` through `9` and space, something like that)? Or just what? Where is it coming from - a text file, user input, etc.? Describe the **whole** process.

Answer (score 0):

If you start with something like this:

`bytearray = [65, 66, 67, 200, 156, 130]`

Then this would do it:

```
>>> ustring = reduce(operator.add, map(chr, bytearray)).decode('shift_jis')
>>> ustring
u'ABC\uff88\u6029'
```